# Pointers in C vs C++

Tags: c++, c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does C++ require a cast for malloc() but C doesn’t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477741/why-does-c-require-a-cast-for-malloc-but-c-doesnt)

This particular piece of code runs fine in C, but gives compilation error when compiled as a C++ program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int (*b)[10];
    b = calloc(20, sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}
```

The error in C++ compilation is:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:9:28: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘int (*)[10]’ [-fpermissive]
```

Any idea what might be the reason?

Comment: Can you specify which C and C++ compilers were used?

Answer (score 7):

While in C you may cast from/to void pointer to other pointer types implicitly, it is not allowed in c++, and you need to cast it explicitly:

```
b = (int (*)[10])calloc(20, sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 1):

`C++` is more strict type checking language than `C`.
So, you need to typecast it manually but in C it's typecasted automatically.

Here calloc returns `void*` and `b` is of type `int(*)[]` hence typecasting is mandatory.

In C++ other type castes are  also available you need to keep in mind

```
<static_cast>
<const_cast>
<reinterpret_cast>
<dynamic_cast>
```

For more see this 
[When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)

Answer (score 0):

C is more permissive when it comes to casting, C++ requires you to be explicit when casting. You should be casting it in the C version as well.

Comment: Actually, in C, the cast is generally regarded as a bad idea since it is verbose and can hide errors. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/485561