# Float data to uint8_t and memcpy , returning null

Tags: c++, c, floating-point

I have a float variable , which needs to be passed as uint8_t to the function .

How do I convert back to float original value .

Code:

```
bool SetAnalog(uint8_t number, float voltage, MessagePriority priority, Callback clbck)
{
    uint8_t args[2];
    args[0] = number;
    memcpy(&(args[1]),&voltage,sizeof(float));

    PTCLoopOutMessage* message = parent()->GetLoopOutMessage(this,
                                                             this->address(),
                                                             _OutputVoltage,
                                                             "DACVoltage",
                                                             args,
                                                             sizeof(args),
                                                             Device,
                                                             priority);
    message->SetCallback(clbck);

    return ProcessOutMessage(message);
}
```

I try to get back the float original value from uint8_t array and need to assign to probe[channel]

```
uint8_t channel = message->GetOutMessage()->GetData()->data[0];
unsigned char* value = &message->GetOutMessage()->GetData()->data[1];
memcpy(&__output.output.probe[channel].dac, value, sizeof(float));
```

I always get value as 0,

Please Help

Comment: Oh wait... 'DACVoltage' - what exactly is GetLoopOutMessage() requiring in that array??

Comment: virtual PTCLoopOutMessage* GetLoopOutMessage(PTCHardware* source, uint8_t address,uint8_t command, const char* commandString, const uint8_t* data, size_t dataLength, PTCMessageType messageType, PTCMessagePriority priority) = 0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
struct MyArgs {
  uint8_t channel;
  float voltage;
} *args = new MyArgs();
args->channel = number;
args->voltage = voltage;
```

Then pass it like this:

```
....GetLoopOutMessage(....., (uint8_t *)args, sizeof(*args), ....)
```

And read the data out like this:

```
struct MyArgs {
  uint8_t channel;
  float voltage;
} *args = (struct MyArgs *)message->GetOutMessage()->GetData()->data;

uint8_t channel = args->channel;
__output.output.probe[channel].dac = args->voltage;

delete args;
```

Note that I've used `new`/`delete` here, not local stack storage, because you appear to be using the data in a callback, so I'm guessing your data has been overwritten (with zero, as it happens) before you get to read it.

---

If `new`/`delete` is inappropriate (`GetLoopOutMessage` makes a copy of the data), then do it like this:

```
struct {
  uint8_t channel;
  float voltage;
} args = {number, voltage};
```

Then pass it like this:

```
....GetLoopOutMessage(....., (uint8_t *)&args, sizeof(args), ....)
```

And read the data out like this:

```
struct mydata {
  uint8_t channel;
  float voltage;
} *args = (struct mydata *)message->GetOutMessage()->GetData()->data;

uint8_t channel = args->channel;
__output.output.probe[channel].dac = args->voltage;
```

Comment: This may work, but if it expects the float right after the uint8 then padding is going to be a problem unless the struct is packed.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: The example given shows both ends of the "pipe", so I doubt the packedness was really required.

Comment: As long as they have acess to changing both sides.  I thought `GetLoopOutMessage` might be a bit of a black box.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: yeah, it looks like the kind of black box that does a straight pass through of the data though. On second thoughts, the `sizeof` attribute suggests that it copies the data, so malloc/free may be a bad plan.

Comment: Answer extended for that case.

Comment: The compiler shows an error " invalid conversion of void* to SetAnalog at the *args=malloc....

Comment: You're using C++? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477741/why-does-c-require-a-cast-for-malloc-but-c-doesnt

Comment: You should probably use `new`/`delete` instead of malloc then.

Comment: I don't do much C++, but I've converted the answer to what I think it should look like.

Comment: You switched your answer. Did this not work for you, after all?

Answer (score 7):

You have undefined behavior in your code. A `float` is normally four bytes long, while `uint8_t` is a single byte. So you overwrite your array with at least three bytes.

Then when you pass it in the `GetLoopOutMessage` you only pass the actual array (which is two bytes), so the floating point number is now missing the majority of its data.

You might want to use e.g.

```
uint8_t args[1 + sizeof(float)];
```

---

If the `GetLoopOutMessage` doesn't copy the data you pass to it, then you have another case of undefined behavior, namely passing around a pointer to a local variable. When the `SetAnalog` function returns, the space in memory where local variables are stored is reused by the next function call. This means that the `args` array no longer exists in memory, and where it used to be there may now be other data.

To solve this you either should make the `args` array `static`, make it global (really not recommended) or to dynamically allocate it on the heap:

```
uint8_t* args = new uint8_t[1 + sizeof(float)];
```

Don't forget to `delete` this pointer once your done with it (i.e. when you retrieved the data).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but still the value holds 0 in spite of changing to args[5].

Comment: I've never seen any 'DAC' hardware stuff that takes a float as an argument, either directly or as byte-copied into an array.

Comment: args array holds the value of args[5]={0,0,0,64,65}, when the probe number is 0 , and the voltage is 12.

Comment: @user2746930 After a quick test my self, the `float` number `12.0` seems to be the byte sequence `0 0 64 65`, so the data is correct. It may however be another problem, actually another case of undefined behavior. Please see my updated answer.