# fill empty linked list from another linked list in c language

Tags: c, list, linked-list

i have a full linked list with data in it, what i want is to fill another linked list with the same data but with a condition, so let say that this is the linked list :

```
char cl; 
int time; 
int lng;
```

> C 0 1
>
> D 0 2
>
> B 2 1
>
> A 2 2

i wan to copy from this list to a new empty one but only if (time>0), so the new one will be like this :

> B 2 1
>
> A 2 2

i have tried this code but it doesn't work :

```
void insert(const node * n )// this where i put the pointer of the full node
{
    node *head=n;
    node *sec; // new node
    sec=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); 

    do{
        if(head->time>0){
            strcpy(sec->cl,head->cl);
            sec->time= head->time;
            sec->lng= head->lng;
            head=head->next;
            sec=sec->next;
        }
        else 
            head=head->next;
    }while(head!=NULL);
    print(sec) // this will print the new node
}
```

Help me please. Thank you

Comment: 'new' is a reserved word in c++ and if the compiler understands both C and C++, it will have a problem.

Comment: How did you create the original linked list? Why can't you use the functions that you have used to build that list?

Comment: Don't use strcpy! strcpy is used to copy strings (null-terminated), but you only have a single char. Use `sec->cl = head->cl;` or it will break your code.

Comment: Or did you forget the * in `char *cl;`? If yes, you forgot to allocate memory for the string.

Comment: You only allocated memory for the first item in `sec` and not subsequent ones, and `sec=sec->next` will cause undefined behaviour, because the field has not been initialised.

Comment: `it doesn't work` - Does it compile? Does the program crash? Does it produce wrong results?

Comment: Remove the `else` before `else head=head->next;`

Comment: `while(head!=NULL)` should be at the top of the loop, not the tail.

Comment: @user3629249 No it's not a problem when compiling C code. If you write C code and compile it as C++ code, then it's a problem. But it has nothing to do with a compiler being able to compile both. A C/C++ compiler compiling C code as C will have no problems with `new` or the compiler is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I combined all the suggestions from the comments as well as some additional fixes.
 Here's the resulting code:

```
const node* insert(const node * head)
{
    node *sec = NULL;  // start of the new, second list
    node *last = NULL; // points to the last inserted node

    while(head!=NULL){
        if(head->time > 0){
            node* newsec=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); 
            newsec->cl = head->cl;
            newsec->time = head->time;
            newsec->lng = head->lng;
            newsec->next = NULL;
            //Add the new node to the list:
            if(last == NULL){ //This is the first element in the new list
               sec = newsec;
            }else{
               last-> next = newsec;
            }
            last = newsec;
        }
        head=head->next;
    }
    print(sec); // this will print the new node
    return sec;
}
```

Your mistakes:

- Wrong memory allocation (You only allocated memory once)
- strcpy is not needed (char's don't require a string-copy)
- while must be at the beginning of the loop (your code would fail if the given list is empty)
- missing semicolon
- wrong concatination of the new list
- wrong const-correctness (Missing const in `node *head=n;`)
- the internal `head`-variable is not neccessary (And the parameter-naming `n` is also not ideal. If you name it "start"/"head"/"begin", the comment wouldn't be neccessary)

Another suggestion: Use an upper case name for your struct, since it makes it easier to distinguish types from variables (should be `Node`, not `node)`.

Note that you might want to remove the `const` from the return value type.

Comment: `node newsec` should be `node *newsec`, and don't cast the result of malloc.

Comment: @Jite I guess that OP is using a C++ compiler, which requires a cast.

Comment: Why would you guess that? It's C code and to compile C code you use a C compiler, even if the compiler can compile C++. There is no need, and its indeed not recommended,  to cast the result of malloc in C. The question is tagged C.

Comment: Shouldn't the routine return `sec` as the head of the copied list?

Comment: @Jite C++ requires the result of malloc to be casted (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477741/why-does-c-require-a-cast-for-malloc-but-c-doesnt) - and although the question is tagged as C, I think that the OP is actually using a C++ compiler since he used `new` in his initial post. If he is in fact using a C compiler, he can remove the cast. (I wanted to ensure that my answer works on his setup.)

Comment: @maja The code would have to be compiled as C++ code for it to be a problem, independent of compiler capabilities.

Answer (score -1):

```
// Note: a better function name might be: printNodesWithTime

void insert(const node * pOld )
{

    // note: since nothing is done with the new linked list,
    //       there is no need to actually create it

    while( NULL != pOld )
    {

        if(pPld->time > 0)
        {
            print(pOld) // this will print the node
        }

        // step to next old node
        pOld = pOld->next;

    } // end while
} // end function: insert
```

Comment: now, if the OP actually wants to keep an 'extracted' linked list then the above would not be a suitable answer

Comment: OP wants to create a copy of the original list, filtered by time.