# C++ Heap corruption after simple action

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-corruption

I can't get why simple actions with my array corrupt the heap.

For example, this code works fine:

```
double *matrix = (double*)(malloc(50));

free(matrix);
```

Then, I try to modify some of the elements of this array like this:

```
double *matrix = (double*)(malloc(50));

for (int i = 0; i < 20; matrix++, i++) {
    *matrix = (double)i;
}

free(matrix);
```

The problem is that even this code is not working at all. (VS tells me that the heap was corrupted). Probably it is a stupid mistake, but I am new to all this actions with pointers.

**UPDATE**

Now my code looks like this:

```
double *matrix = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * 50);
```

But I got this error message:

[image]

Comment: you only malloced 50 ( thats 50 bytes not 50 doubles )

Comment: So it shoud be like malloc(sizeof(double)*50)?

Comment: correct, and you should check the return code from malloc also

Comment: But why do I need (double*) than?

Comment: you only need the (double*) cast because c++ cant handle the types properly. see **[why c++ requires malloc cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477741/why-does-c-require-a-cast-for-malloc-but-c-doesnt)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code modified the pointer "matrix" before you free it, which I believe is an undefined behavior.

No offense, but I suggest you get a good book about c++. "malloc" is not the preferred way for dynamic memory allocation in c++.

Anyway, if you would like to access the memory block as an array, the preferable way to do it is to use operator[]:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    matrix[i] = (double)i;
}
```

And yes, as @Hernantas mentioned, if you want to allocate a space for 50 double objects, use

```
myVar = malloc (sizeof(double) * 50);
```

Comment: Thank you. I fixed this problem. I am reading "The C programming language".  I modified it because, as I understand, it do not change when modified inside other functions. For example, in function doStuff() I can write something like this: matrix+=1000; But in main function matrix still points at zero array element. Did I get it right?

Comment: @CMTV weather the original "matrix" is modified depends on how the argument is passed. If the pointer is pass by value then the change will not affect the original variable.

Comment: Does it mean, that by passing pointer this way: doStuff(int *p) I pass only the value of "p" (and that is why chaning it actually changes nothing in other functions) but *p still is a link to a specific array element?

Comment: @CMTV `doStuff(int *p)` is actually passed-by-value: the value of the pointer itself is copied into the function. If you change the value of p inside doStuff (not changing what it points to), say `p = someOtherPointer`, p will point to a new position while the original pointer will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

What your malloc do is allocated 50 bytes, not 50 double. Here are example of how to use malloc:

```
myVar = (double*)malloc (sizeof(double));
```

or if you want to use multiple (array) double then you can do it like this:

```
myVar = (double*)malloc (sizeof(double) * 50);
```

Comment: Thank you, but i got another error after changing the code.