# Dynamic memory allocation for structs in c

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic, struct, malloc

I am trying to initialise a struct by allocating memory to it and it's pointer members using malloc:

```
typedef struct {
    char *name;
    prob_t *prob;
} name_t;
```

I understand that I need to allocate memory to the pointers separately once the struct is initialised:

```
name_t
*init_name_dict() {
    name_t *name_dict;
    name_dict = (name_t*)malloc(MAX_LINES*sizeof(*name_dict));
    name_dict->name = (char*)malloc(MAX_LEN*sizeof(*name_dict->name));
    name_dict->prob = (prob_t*)malloc(MAX_PROB*sizeof(*name_dict->prob));
    return name_dict;
}
```

But when I do so, it allocates memory to the struct, but not to either of its member pointers (they just point to junk).

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: The `malloc` method doesn't "clean" the memory it returns. Use `calloc` if you want zeroed memory, or `memset` it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538420/difference-between-malloc-and-calloc

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, except that you do not check `malloc()`'s return value and that it is unnecessary to cast the return value of `malloc()` in C.  And note well the distinction implicit in @xanatos's comment: a valid pointer to space with junk in it is not at all the same thing as an invalid pointer.  When `malloc()` fails, it returns a null pointer.

Comment: In C all those cast are needless.

Answer (score 4):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538420/difference-between-malloc-and-calloc), `malloc` doesn't "clean" the memory, that then can be full of garbage (because for example the same memory was returned by another call to `malloc()`, used and then `free()`). The three classical solutions are:

- Live with it. Set manually all the members of the `struct` (if you are
  using the `malloc` to allocate a `struct`) before using the `struct` (or in general set the all the obtained memory to the value you want)
- Use `memset` to zero all the memory before using it
- Use `calloc` instead of `malloc` (note that it has a slightly different signature). `calloc` is similar to `malloc` + `memset`. As an example:

```
name_t *init_name_dict() {
    name_t *name_dict;
    name_dict = calloc(MAX_LINES, sizeof(*name_dict));
    name_dict->name = calloc(MAX_LEN, sizeof(*name_dict->name));
    name_dict->prob = calloc(MAX_PROB, sizeof(*name_dict->prob));
    return name_dict;
}
```

As a sidenote, in C you don't need/shouldn't cast a pointer returned by `malloc`/`calloc` ([but if in truth you are using a C++ compiler then you have to cast it...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477741/why-does-c-require-a-cast-for-malloc-but-c-doesnt)).

Answer (score 1):

If you want cleared memory (as opposed to memory with junk in it), you need `calloc`
instead of `malloc`, but that's trivial.

You're bigger problems are:

```
1) no error checking
2) possibly needless malloc calls
3) you're allocating MAX_LINES of theses name_t structure but initializing 
  only one of them
```

If the `.name` and `.prob` fields won't be reallocated, you should change your `name_t`
definition to

```
typedef struct { char name[MAX_LEN]; prob_t prob[MAX_PROB]; } name_t;
```

and allocate all MAX_LINES name_t's in one go: `calloc(MAX_LINES, sizeof(name_t))`.

If you need the original `name_t` structure, then I'd have an initializer for one:

```
int init_name_dict (name_t  *this)
{
    if(0==(this->name=calloc(MAX_LEN, sizeof *this->name))) return -1;
    if(0==(this->prob=calloc(MAX_PROB, sizeof *this->prob))){ free(this->name); return -1; }
    return 0;
}
```

a destructor for it

```
void destroy_name_dict(name_t *this) { free(this->name); free(this->prob); }
```

and then an initializing allocator for the whole array:

```
name_t* new_name_dicts(void)
{
    name_t *r = malloc(MAX_LINES*sizeof *r);
    if(!r) return r;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<MAX_LINES; i++)
        if(0>init_name_dict(&r[i])) goto fail;
    return r;
    fail:
        for(--i; i>=0; --i)
            destructor_name_dict(&r[i]);
    return NULL;
}
```

(Basically what would amount to a C++ vector constructor that picks up the constructor for the
 cell type.)

Answer (score -1):

Struct

```
typedef struct {
    char *name;
    prob_t *prob;
} name_t;
```

has two pointers as members. So on 32 bit OS, `sizeof(name_t)` is 8 bytes.
Dynamic creation of instance of `name_t` struct

```
name_t *name_dict = (name_t*)malloc(sizeof(name_dict));
```

allocates only 8 bytes to store two pointers. As xanatos said allocated memory is garbage and pointers will point random locations. You can use `calloc()` when allocation `name_dict` or manually nullify them `name_dict->name = NULL;name_dict->prob = NULL;`. You can also don't bother yourself by content of pointers and in next code line allocate memory to members

```
name_dict->name = (char*)malloc(MAX_LEN*sizeof(char));
name_dict->prob = (prob_t*)malloc(sizeof(prob_t));
```

You can also check if memory was allocated good and both pointers don't ppoint to NULL.

To sum up, properly written init_name_dict() method

```
name_t * init_name_dict() 
{
  name_t *name_dict = (name_t*)malloc(sizeof(name_t));
  if  (name_dict != NULL)
  {
        name_dict->name = (char*)malloc(MAX_LEN*sizeof(char)));
        name_dict->prob = (prob_t*)malloc(sizeof(prob_t));
  }
  return name_dict;
 }
```

**Errors** in your code was

- MAX_LINES here(assume that you want to create only one structure here)

  `name_dict = (name_t*)malloc(MAX_LINES*sizeof(*name_dict));`
- MAX_PROB here (assume that you want to create only one structure
  here)

  `name_dict->prob = (prob_t*)malloc(MAX_PROB*sizeof(*name_dict->prob));`

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the OP's main problem.  Although his code would be more robust if it checked the results of his `malloc()` calls, it is basically ok.  His is a problem of wrong expectations about the contents of the memory to which his (properly allocated) pointers point.

Comment: This `name_t *name_dict = (name_t*)malloc(sizeof(name_dict));` is wrong, as it allocates just the size of a pointer. The OP does it right.

Comment: You missed to correct this "*So on 32 bit OS, `sizeof(name_t)` is 8 bytes.*"

Comment: Also why do you mention this: "*Dynamic creation of instance of `name_t` struct

`name_t *name_dict = (name_t*)malloc(sizeof(name_dict));` allocates only 8 bytes to store two pointers.*"? The OP is not doing it this way.