# This works in c but throws C++ a value of type int * cannot be assigned to an entity of type void *

Tags: c++

```
#define MALLOC(p,s)\
if(!(p=malloc(s)))\
    printf("Not enough memory");
```

```
#define MALLOC(ptr,s)\
if(!(ptr=malloc(s)))\
    std::cout<<"Not enough memory";
```

This runs perfectly in c but in cpp it throws error int* cannot be converted to void*

Comment: You misquoted the error. See [Why does C++ require a cast for malloc() but C doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477741/why-does-c-require-a-cast-for-malloc-but-c-doesnt)

Comment: Very BAD  macro. Never do it! `if (!p) MALLOC(p, 10) else printf("p already assigned\n");`

Answer (score 3):

It is the other way around: `void*` cannot be converted to `int*` in `C++` - unlike in `C`.

`malloc` returns `void*`, and apparently you invoke this macro with `int* ptr`. You can make the 2nd macro compiled in `C++` in this particular case by adding a cast:

```
#define MALLOC(ptr,s)\
if(!(ptr=static_cast<int*>(malloc(s))))\
    std::cout<<"Not enough memory";
```

Or more general (starting from `C++11`):

```
#define MALLOC(ptr,s)\
if(!(ptr=static_cast<decltype(ptr)>(malloc(s))))\
    std::cout<<"Not enough memory";
```

Of course, idiomatic `C++` does not use `malloc()` at all.

Comment: Does that mean in C we can type cast the void pointer ?

Comment: In C `void*` is convertible to any other pointer w/o explicit cast.